What is the toughness of the Tutte graph?
The Tutte graph

is a $3$-regular graph with $46$ vertices and $69$ edges named after W. T. Tutte.
The toughness $\tau$ of a graph $G$ is
$$\tau(G)=\min_{S} \left\{\frac{|S|}{c(G-S)}\right\},$$
where $c(G)$ denotes the number of connected components of a graph $G$, and the minimum is taken over all $S$ that are cutsets of vertices in $G$.
We know that Tutte graph is non-Hamiltonian. I'm curious about what its toughness is equal to. A weak question  is, is its toughness greater than or equal to $1$?
My motivation is to know whether the non-Hamiltonian property of Tutte graph can be explained by its toughness.

A computer search confirms that the toughness is $\frac87$. Here is a way we can achieve this, creating $7$ components by deleting $8$ vertices:

The Tutte graph has too many vertices to analyze by brute force, so here is the alternate strategy we will use.
Consider the Tutte fragment: the graph below. (The Tutte graph is obtained by stitching three of these together.)

We will consider candidate vertex sets $S$ to delete from the interior of the Tutte fragment (that is, excluding the three degree-$1$ vertices) under several hypotheses:

Each of the three degree-$1$ vertices may be present or already deleted.
For the degree-$1$ vertices that are present, they may be connected to each other outside the fragment or not.

Here is a list of the $15$ possible hypotheses, in a shorthand notation: $\{\}$, $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{3\}$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{12\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{13\}$, $\{2,3\}$, $\{23\}$, $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{12,3\}$, $\{1,23\}$, $\{13,2\}$, $\{123\}$. (I write $1$, $2$, and $3$ to indicate which vertices are present, and write them together as $12$ if they are connected and separately as $1,2$ if not.)
Under each hypothesis, we will find the optimal $S$ to delete (the one that leaves the most connected components) for each value of $|S|$. We should feel free to exclude sets that don't do better than a smaller set (for instance, a $7$-vertex set that leaves $4$ components is always worse than a $5$-vertex set that leaves $4$ components), but we don't try to measure ratios yet: we consider a $7$-vertex set that leaves $4$ components to be incomparable to a $6$-vertex set that leaves $3$ components. In other words, we are finding all the sets on the "Pareto frontier" of the size/number-of-components tradeoff. (One candidate set is always the empty set; it is the best set of its size!)
Then, we collect all the sets we found under all the hypotheses into a single family $\mathcal F$. Lots of sets are repeated with different hypothesis, which helps keep $\mathcal F$ small; when I did this, I got $|\mathcal F| = 53$, but I did not fully eliminate suboptimal sets, so this could get even smaller.
The reason we're doing this is that, in the overall Tutte graph, the optimal cut-set that achieves the toughness must intersect each "third" of the graph in a set from $\mathcal F$. This leaves us with only $2|\mathcal F|^3$ cases to check: From each third of the graph, we select a set corresponding to some set from $\mathcal F$, and also we either do or don't delete the center vertex.
$2|\mathcal F|^3$ is small enough to handle by brute force! Excluding the cases that are not cut-sets, I found six optimal sets all achieving a toughness of $\frac87$, as in the diagram at the beginning of this answer.

Nice. I believe it is correct. However, I didn't quite understand some parts of your answer. Would you consider providing a more detailed explanation? For example, the notation for the 15 possible hypotheses —I don't understand their meaning.

@licheng I assume e.g. {12,3} means all three are present with 1 and 2 being connected outside the fragment.

@licheng The comment above is correct, and I've edited to clarify. Are there other things you think should be more detailed?

One way to answer the weak question is the following. Suppose a graph $G$ has two adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ such that $G-u$ and $G-v$ are Hamiltonian. Then $G$ is $1$-tough. To prove this, suppose we remove $k$ vertices and there are more than $k$ components. Since $G-u$ is $1$-tough, at most $k$ of these components can intersect $G-u$, i.e. one component must be $\{u\}$. But the same applies to $v$, which is a contradiction since they are adjacent.
Now removing either of the marked vertices allows a path through the bottom fragment, from bottom left to bottom right, covering the remaining vertices, and such a path can be extended to a Hamilton cycle.


Thank you. Nice idea! But I note that  the answer due to Misha Lavrov is stronger.
